# How to get Uploaded Url of a Video File in android using Parse REST API

Tags: parse-platform

I am using Parse Mobile Backend for my android app,but whenever I want to upload a large video more than the default 10mb limit for a `ParseFile`by getting the bytes from it into a ParseFile I keep  running into the dreaded `OutOfMemory Exception` .So,I want to use the Parse REST API since I can easily use the `setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)` in `HttpUrlConnection`to send the bytes in a chunked manner.The trouble is,how do I get the uploaded url of the file uploaded.Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use getUrl() method

```
 ParseFile file = new ParseFile(byte[] data);
 file.getUrl();
```

ParseFile object has getUrl() method to getting url of file. this method return URL in string format.